# SPF record and problem sending email

Tags: google, email

[image: kupissimo.com]

Is this correct setting for SPF record. Should i use double quotes or not in DATA part?

Even with this I have problem rejecting emails from google:

```
host
gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c00::1a] said: 550-5.7.1
[2a02:c200:0:10:3:2:843:1      12] Our system has detected that this
550-5.7.1 message is likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam
sent 550-5.7.1 to Gmail, this message has been blocked. Please visit
550-5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131
for 550 5.7.1 more information. 4si4196823qcl.68 - gsmtp (in reply to end
of DATA command)
```

Comment: As answered below, you do have a [missing](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=spf%3akupissimo.com&run=toolpage#) TXT record. Also, the Reverse DNS (PTR) record for the IP in your screenshot resolves to: [mail.djuric.org](http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=ptr%3a79.143.181.241&run=toolpage). Check with your host or ISP as to how to setup Reverse DNS. Lastly, have you checked RBL databases to see if your IP is listed? It's listed in [this](http://v4bl.org/delist/) one as indicated [here](http://multirbl.valli.org/lookup/79.143.181.241.html).

Comment: I have djuric.org and kupissimo.com on same IP address and same tomcat. I can defined only one PTR record, correct?

Comment: It's generally not recommended to have [multiple PTR records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_DNS_lookup#Multiple_pointer_records), though templates for control panels typically add them automatically. You might designate the PTR for the domain that your mail server is associated with, so that mail servers can match the IP with the mail servers's host.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the screenshot you have the zone “type” for the SPF record set as `SPF` when it should be `TXT`. Is that `SPF` zone type a preset from your control panel? Or did you manually enter it? Regardless, it needs to be `TXT`. [This site](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch9/spf.html) explains it well:

```
The SPF information must be defined using a standard TXT resource record (RR).
```

Also, I am not sure if `mx` is needed, so would recommend using this instead:

```
"v=spf1 ip4:79.143.181.241 ~all"
```